# Gradient of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Gradient is supposed to point in the direction of steepest ascent, but when I try to find the gradient of $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ I get $(2x, 2y)$ and at $(0,0)$ this is $(0,0)$, but what does this gradient vector mean? When looking at $f(x,y)$ on a graph, I can see that any direction you go the graph will increase, so shouldn’t there be some direction the gradient points in?

Comment: Apparently, no.

Answer (score 3):

Of course not. The function $f$ has a **minimum** at $(0,0)$. So, you should expect that the gradient there is $(0,0)$.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused, since I thought the gradient gives a direction to go for maximum increase, but the gradient isn't pointing anywhere in this example?

Comment: Wouldn't the gradient at least be pointing in any one direction since it is a minimum though? Wouldn't a minimum mean that the gradient should have some direction for the function to increase?

Comment: Which direction? It **doesn't** grow at that point.